what are from_messages, from_template, format, format_messages in language? Can someone simplify?
Can you give me the context on when to use and why of the above mentioned functions?
I tried reading the docs but couldn't understand much. Any referecnces to blogs or links for this would be helpful as well.
Here are the docs I referred to
PromptTemplate -
https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/prompts/langchain_core.prompts.prompt.PromptTemplate.html
ChatPromptTemplate - https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/prompts/langchain_core.prompts.chat.ChatPromptTemplate.html
Thanks in advance.

you could at least add links to documentation

Sure.
PromptTemplate - https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/prompts/langchain_core.prompts.prompt.PromptTemplate.html
ChatPromptTemplate -
https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/prompts/langchain_core.prompts.chat.ChatPromptTemplate.html

you could add links in question - not in comments. They will more visible for other people, so more people may help you.

you should go to source code implementation. in the code they comment out and also you can see what is going on. those methods are actually instantiating the class instance with extra configuration and validation. for example, if you look at from_messages implementation:
@classmethod
    def from_messages(
        cls,
        messages: Sequence[
            Union[
                BaseMessagePromptTemplate,
                BaseChatPromptTemplate,
                BaseMessage,
                Tuple[str, str],
                Tuple[Type, str],
                str,
            ]
        ],
    ) -> ChatPromptTemplate:
        """Create a chat prompt template from a variety of message formats.

        Examples:

            Instantiation from a list of message templates:

            .. code-block:: python

                template = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([
                    ("human", "Hello, how are you?"),
                    ("ai", "I'm doing well, thanks!"),
                    ("human", "That's good to hear."),
                ])

            Instantiation from mixed message formats:

            .. code-block:: python

                template = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([
                    SystemMessage(content="hello"),
                    ("human", "Hello, how are you?"),
                ])

        Args:
            messages: sequence of message representations.
                  A message can be represented using the following formats:
                  (1) BaseMessagePromptTemplate, (2) BaseMessage, (3) 2-tuple of
                  (message type, template); e.g., ("human", "{user_input}"),
                  (4) 2-tuple of (message class, template), (4) a string which is
                  shorthand for ("human", template); e.g., "{user_input}"

        Returns:
            a chat prompt template
        """
        _messages = [_convert_to_message(message) for message in messages]

        # Automatically infer input variables from messages
        input_vars = set()
        for _message in _messages:
            if isinstance(
                _message, (BaseChatPromptTemplate, BaseMessagePromptTemplate)
            ):
                input_vars.update(_message.input_variables)

        return cls(input_variables=sorted(input_vars), messages=_messages)

this method,

first using _convert_to_message helper, it converts each message into a standardized format that the ChatPromptTemplate class can work with

then it elinates the duplicate messages with using input_vars = set.

The input_variables are placeholders in the message templates that will be replaced with actual values when the template is used. For example, a message might have a template like "Hello, {user_name}!", where {user_name} is an input variable.

then it checks what kind of messages they accept: BaseChatPromptTemplate, BaseMessagePromptTemplate


After collecting all unique input variables, it returns
   return cls(input_variables=sorted(input_vars), messages=_messages)

This line creates and returns an instance of ChatPromptTemplate using the inferred input variables and the processed messages.
this is from_template method:
  @classmethod
    def from_template(
        cls: Type[MessagePromptTemplateT],
        template: str,
        template_format: str = "f-string",
        **kwargs: Any,
    ) -> MessagePromptTemplateT:
        """Create a class from a string template.

        Args:
            template: a template.
            template_format: format of the template.
            **kwargs: keyword arguments to pass to the constructor.

        Returns:
            A new instance of this class.
        """
        prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template(template, template_format=template_format)
        return cls(prompt=prompt, **kwargs)

from_template takes a single template string (and optional format) to create an instance. from_messages takes a sequence of messages in various formats to create an instance.

Thanks for the explanation. I see that PromptTemplate has from_template but ChatPromptTemplate has both from_template and from_messages. Since ChatPromptTemplate has both the functions, is there no need to PromptTemplate at all? Please correct my understanding if there are any gaps

let me make it clear : every llm needs a prompt to produce output.
the prompt that we are providing to the llm could be either in string format or list of chat messages.
from_messages:
the chat messages are different types [only few said below ]:
human message: message from user.
AI message:message from model.
system message: this tells our model how to behave.

from_messages accepts variety of chat messages and based on them it provides output .
    from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
    
    chat_template = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
        [
            ("system", "You are a helpful AI bot. Your name is {name}."),
            ("human", "Hello, how are you doing?"),
            ("ai", "I'm doing well, thanks!"),
            ("human", "{user_input}"),
        ]
    )
    
    messages = chat_template.format_messages(name="Bob", user_input="What is your name?")
    llm=ChatTogether(api_key='*************************************')
    llm.invoke(messages)
#output: AIMessage(content="My name is Bob! Nice to meet you! I'm a helpful AI bot here to assist you with any questions or tasks you may have.")

from_template: this Load's a prompt template from a template given inside .
from langchain_core.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain_together import ChatTogether
prompt_template = PromptTemplate.from_template(
    "Tell me a {adjective} joke about {content}."
)
prompt_template.format(adjective="funny", content="chickens")
llm=ChatTogether(api_key='*****************************************')
lcel_Chain=prompt_template|llm
lcel_Chain.invoke({"adjective":"funny", "content":"cats"})
#output:AIMessage(content='Why did the cat join a band?\n\nBecause it wanted to be the purr-cussionist!)

Format:this is used to Format the prompt with the inputs.
( in below code name and place are inputs )

from langchain_core.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain_together import ChatTogether
prompt=prompt_template.from_template('''
have you heard about animal called {**name**} and the its count in {**place**} ''',variables=['name','place'])

final_formatted_prompt=prompt.format(name='lion', place='india')
llm=ChatTogether(api_key='*****************************************')

lcel_Chain=prompt_template|llm

llm.invoke(final_formatted_prompt)

#output:AIMessage(content="A great topic!\n\nYes, I'm familiar with lions and their population in India .....)

